# Error when using Ant design's Grid.useBreakpoint() on a nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, antd, next.js13

a beginner here.
I am using ant design component library and nextjs framework to develop a front-end application. However, I get errors when using ant design's useBreakpoint(). Here is a code snippet:

```
//using the nextjs app routing convention

"use client";
import "@/styles/global.css";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Sidebar from "@/components/frame/sidebar/sidebar";
import Topbar from "./top-bar";
import {Button, Layout, Grid} from "antd";
import {MenuOutlined} from "@ant-design/icons";

function Frame({children}) {
    const {useBreakpoint} = Grid;
    
    const screens = useBreakpoint();

    const {Content} = Layout;
    const [desktopToggleState, setdesktopToggleState] = useState(false);
    const [mobileToggleState, setmobileToggleState] = useState(false);

    const handleMobileToggleState = () => {
        setmobileToggleState(!mobileToggleState);
    };

    const handleDesktopToggleState = () => {
        setdesktopToggleState(!desktopToggleState);
    };
```

below is the error I get on the browser
[image]

I have done a lot of searching but am yet to get a solution. Please help me.
Weirdly, even after removing that piece of code I still get the same error but the browser doen't point me to that line of code

Comment: I don't think this is something releated to antd or breakpoints as you said if you remove this line you still get this error. I'll suggest you to delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstall all your project dependencies and also delete `.next` folder and then start again your project and see if the error is gone.

I don't know if this is related but worth a try: In my project I've declared `const { useBreakpoint } = Grid` outside of function body. Hope this helps